# QWidgetAction doesn't work inside QMenu as a context menu for tray

Tags: qt, qt5, qmenu, qwidgetaction

I'm trying to insert a `QWidgetAction` inside a `QMenu`, which will be used as a context menu for tray. When I do this, I only get an empty line inside my menu.

I'm using:

- Qt 5.5.1.
- Plasma 5 desktop environment (Linux).

Here is my code:

```
action = new QWidgetAction(0);
testw = new QWidget();
testl = new QLabel(QString("Test"), testw);

action->setDefaultWidget(testw);

menu.addAction(action);
trayIcon.setContextMenu(&menu);
```

If I use `menu.addAction(QString("Test"))`; it is displayed properly.

All the variables are members of my class.

Comment: I don't think that can possibly work. Menus of system tray icons are not managed by the application; the "description" of the menu is serialized through DBus. Hence you can't embed widgets in there.

Comment: I've tried the solution by @AlexanderVX and similar approaches but (like @peppe says) this doesn't work for me in the system tray (i'm running Lubuntu 14.04). However the workaround that i'm using -- since in my case i only need to display text -- is to call the `setDisabled` method for the `QAction` that i want to use as a label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you already have the menu shown then the problem is with extra widget you wrap the QLabel with. This is the way QWdigetAction usually works:

```
QWidgetAction* pWidgetAction = new QWidgetAction(0); // no parent-owner?
QLabel* pLabelWidget = new QLabel("Test");           // label widget
pWidgetAction->setDefaultWidget(pLabelWidget);       // label is a widget
menu.addAction(pWidgetAction);                       // add widget action
trayIcon.setContextMenu(&menu);                      // this I assume works
```

Also unsure of the life-cycle of these objects (the ownership) and why `menu` and `trayIcon` are not pointers but you should be more clear about that. By default I always create UI objects with `new` and pass the parent widget/object address to constructor though we can have those on stack as well (not flexible approach).

Comment: With Qt 5.12 on Ubuntu 19.10 this solution does work.